# Java extract colorSpace and PCS from ICC_Profile to verify the integrety of an image

Tags: java, image, colors, metadata, exif

First (I forgot to say I'm new to java and it's my first post here, so if I make some mistakes, pls correct me ;) )
I got the problem, that I got a lot of images. Between these images are some which are corruped (e.g. a picture with ICC-Profile CMYK and Lab has the pixel-scheme RGB or other example ICC: RGB and XYZ and pixel-scheme CMYK). I need to programm a Java application to test these files for this specific category.

FileTypes are: JPG,TIFF,GIF,PNG and BMP.

I installed already ImageIO and ImageIO from twelvemonkeys to accept CMYK-Files. I tried to read out the Meta/exif-data and also the ICC-data but it didn't show me the information I need.

I tried to read out the Data with PhotoMe but therefor I have to look up all files one by one and compare it by hand. So I knew the data is in the files and not empty.

So the goal is to read out the metadata and ICC-Profil and compare the specific values.

Thanks
Zorian

Edit: I managed to get the Pixel-Scheme, I think, but I can't acces the other informations. Here's the code to acces the Pixel-Scheme (or ColorSpace). So Have u got an idea of getting the other things?

```
int cst = 0;
ColorSpace cs= image.getColorModel().getColorSpace();
System.out.println("--> "+cs.getType());
cst = cs.getType();
PixelScheme pisc = new PixelScheme();
pisc.showPixelSchema(cst);
log.append("Pixel-Scheme = " + pisc.showPixelScheme(cst) + "\n");



//Class Pixel-Scheme
//the Case values taken from a table from java.awt.color.ColorSpace;

package components;

import java.awt.color.ColorSpace;


public class PixelSchema {

    public String showPixelSchema (int cst)
    {

            switch (cst)
            {
                case 0: ptype = "XYZ";
                    break;
                case 1: ptype = "Lab";
                    break;
                case 2: ptype = "Luv";
                    break;
                case 3: ptype = "YCbCr";
                    break;
                case 4: ptype = "Yxy";
                    break;
                case 5: ptype = "RGB";
                    break;
                case 6: ptype = "GRAY";
                    break;
                case 7: ptype = "HSV";
                    break;
                case 8: ptype = "HLS";
                    break;
                case 9: ptype = "CMYK";
                    break;
                case 11: ptype = "CMY";
                    break;
                case 12: ptype = "2CLR";
                    break;
                case 13: ptype = "3CLR";
                    break;
                case 14: ptype = "4CLR";
                    break;
                case 15: ptype = "5CLR";
                    break;
                case 16: ptype = "6CLR";
                    break;
                case 17: ptype = "7CLR";
                    break;
                case 18: ptype = "8CLR";
                    break;
                case 19: ptype = "9CLR";
                    break;
                case 20: ptype = "ACLR";
                    break;
                case 21: ptype = "BCLR";
                    break;
                case 22: ptype = "CCLR";
                    break;
                case 23: ptype = "DCLR";
                    break;
                case 24: ptype = "ECLR";
                    break;
                case 25: ptype = "FCLR";
                    break;
                case 1000: ptype = "sRGB";
                    break;
                case 1001: ptype = "CIEXYZ";
                    break;
                case 1002: ptype = "PYCC";
                    break;
                case 1003: ptype = "GRAY";
                    break; 
                case 1004: ptype = "LINEAR_RGB";
                    break; 
                default: ptype = "ERROR!";
                    break;
            }

        return ptype;
        }
}
```

---

Update:
I implemented the snippet but got still an error in Netbeans but somehow it work and display me the needed data.

```
public void ICC(File file) throws IOException
    {
      //Error indicated cause of file (but I don't know an other way to import my image (tried to convert it to some kinds of arrays but it won't work))
      Map<MetadataType, Metadata> metadataMap = Metadata.readMetadata(file));
            ICCProfile icc_profile = (ICCProfile)metadataMap.get(MetadataType.ICC_PROFILE);

            if(icc_profile != null) {
                icc_profile.showMetadata();
                log.append("PCS = ");
                log.append("Color Space = ");
            }   
    }
```

But now my question is:
Is there the possibility to get only this two pieces of data 
[Color Space: CMYK + 
PCS: Lab]  out of the header and write them to a variable? (The two ones in the brackets)
I need it because I have to display the results of the Color Space and PCS and compare it to the PixelScheme.

---

Update 2:
I finally got to all data I need, but still got the problem from Update 1!
Here's my code snippet for this Error!

```
public void ICC(File file) throws IOException
{          

Map<MetadataType, Metadata> metadataMap = Metadata.readMetadata(file);
ICCProfile icc_profile = (ICCProfile)metadataMap.get(MetadataType.ICC_PROFILE);

                 if(icc_profile != null) 
                 {
                    icc_profile.showMetadata();
                    String iccs =  icc_profile.getReader().getColorSpace();
                    String icpcs = icc_profile.getReader().getPCS();
                    log.append("Color Space = " + iccs + "\n");
                    log.append("PCS = " + icpcs + "\n");
                  }   
}
```

---

Update 3:
Error found ;) it was 1 ) too much

Thanks a lot for this lib!

Comment: I don't think there is a one-to-one mapping between ICC_Profile colorSpace and those from PixelSchema plus there might be some colorSpace conversion in the process of image reading. So when it comes to BufferedImage, colorSpace may have already been changed.

Comment: I test if there is any one-by-one mapping cause I write the tool and test my results with some pickouts (for PhotoMe and other programs) of the whole images to verify it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to try [icafe](https://github.com/dragon66/icafe). It support extracting ICC_Profile from TIFF, JPEG, PNG. The following is some information from a specific run:

```
*** Start of ICC_Profile Header ***
Profile Size: 3144
CMM Type: Lino
Version: 2.10
Profile/Device Class: 'mntr': display devices - CRTs and LCDs
Color Space: RGB 
PCS: XYZ 
Date Created: 1998/2/9, 6:49:0
Profile File Signature: acsp
Primary Platform Signature: MSFT
Flags: not embedded, used independently
Device Manufacturer: IEC 
Device Model: sRGB
Device Attributes: reflective, glossy, positive, color
Rendering Intent: media-relative colorimetric
PCS Illuminant: X = 0.9642029, Y = 1.0, Z = 0.8249054
Profile Creator: HP  
Profile ID: [0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00]
*** End of ICC_Profile Header ***
*** Start of ICC_Profile Tag Table ***
Tag Count: 17
Tag# 0, Tag Name: bTRC (blueTRCTag), Data Offset: 1084, Data Length: 2060
Tag# 1, Tag Name: bXYZ (blueMatrixColumnTag), Data Offset: 576, Data Length: 20
Tag# 2, Tag Name: BKPT (mediaBlackPointTag), Data Offset: 516, Data Length: 20
Tag# 3, Tag Name: cprt (copyrightTag), Data Offset: 336, Data Length: 51
Tag# 4, Tag Name: desc (profileDescriptionTag), Data Offset: 388, Data Length: 108
Tag# 5, Tag Name: dmdd (deviceModelDescTag), Data Offset: 708, Data Length: 136
Tag# 6, Tag Name: dmnd (deviceMfgDescTag), Data Offset: 596, Data Length: 112
Tag# 7, Tag Name: gTRC (greenTRCTag), Data Offset: 1084, Data Length: 2060
Tag# 8, Tag Name: gXYZ (greenMatrixColumnTag), Data Offset: 556, Data Length: 20
Tag# 9, Tag Name: lumi (luminanceTag), Data Offset: 1016, Data Length: 20
Tag# 10, Tag Name: meas (measurementTag), Data Offset: 1036, Data Length: 36
Tag# 11, Tag Name: rTRC (redTRCTag), Data Offset: 1084, Data Length: 2060
Tag# 12, Tag Name: rXYZ (redMatrixColumnTag), Data Offset: 536, Data Length: 20
Tag# 13, Tag Name: tech (technologyTag), Data Offset: 1072, Data Length: 12
Tag# 14, Tag Name: view (viewingConditionsTag), Data Offset: 980, Data Length: 36
Tag# 15, Tag Name: vued (viewingCondDescTag), Data Offset: 844, Data Length: 134
Tag# 16, Tag Name: wtpt (mediaWhitePointTag), Data Offset: 496, Data Length: 20
*** End of ICC_Profile Tag Table ***
```

Here is a code sample to start with:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.Iterator;

    import com.icafe4j.image.meta.Metadata;
    import com.icafe4j.image.meta.MetadataEntry;
    import com.icafe4j.image.meta.MetadataType;
    import com.icafe4j.image.meta.icc.ICCProfile;

    public class ExtractICCProfile {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            Map<MetadataType, Metadata> metadataMap = Metadata.readMetadata(args[0]);
            ICCProfile icc_profile = (ICCProfile)metadataMap.get(MetadataType.ICC_PROFILE);

            if(icc_profile != null) {
                Iterator<MetadataEntry> iterator = icc_profile.iterator();

                while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                    MetadataEntry item = iterator.next();
                    printMetadata(item, "", "     ");
                }
            }   
        }
        private void printMetadata(MetadataEntry entry, String indent, String increment) {
            logger.info(indent + entry.getKey() (StringUtils.isNullOrEmpty(entry.getValue())? "" : ": " + entry.getValue()));
            if(entry.isMetadataEntryGroup()) {
                 indent += increment;
                 Collection<MetadataEntry> entries = entry.getMetadataEntries();
                 for(MetadataEntry e : entries) {
                    printMetadata(e, indent, increment);
                 }          
            }
        }   
    }
```

Grab "**icafe.jar**" from the "lib" directory of the above link and you are good to go test with the code sample.

**Update:** your can show only colorSpace and PCS like this:

```
if(icc_profile != null) 
{  
   String colorSpace = icc_profile.getColorSpace();
   String pcs = icc_profile.getPCS();
}
```

**Update 2:**

If you need to read further data from a specific tag, you can grab the tag table first and then get the tag entry you are interested in. Here is a snippet:

```
    public void readTag(ProfileTag tag) {
        ProfileTagTable tagTable = reader.getTagTable();
        TagEntry tag = tagTable.getTagEntry(tag);
        // Do your stuff with tag entry
    }
```

And here is the nested TagEntry class:

```
    public static class TagEntry implements Comparable<TagEntry> {
        private int profileTag;
        private int dataOffset;
        private int dataLength;
        private byte[] data;

        public TagEntry(int profileTag, int dataOffset, int dataLength, byte[] data) {
            this.profileTag  = profileTag;
            this.dataOffset = dataOffset;
            this.dataLength = dataLength;
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(TagEntry o) {
            return (int)((this.profileTag&0xffffffffL) - (o.profileTag&0x0ffffffffL));
        }

        public int getProfileTag() {
            return profileTag;
        }

        public int getDataOffset() {
            return dataOffset;
        }

        public int getDataLength() {
            return dataLength;
        }

        public byte[] getData() {
            return data;
        }       
    }
```

Comment: First: Thanks for icafe.jar I try it out but cause I'm still learning java it's hard to get into it ;) I post my results as soon as I recieve some information.

I made an Update to my first post, I hope u can give me a hint on that.

Comment: I found it -.-" bad mistake 1 ')' too much.... yeah I found the PCS and ColorSpace too, after I searched deeper in ur lib   -> i wish I can give u a vote but I haven't the reputation ;) thanks for help and have a nice day